# GLB export scale problem

Tags: export, transforms, shape-keys, gltf

I'd appreciate any help with this. I may be missing something obvious.
I'm having problems with exporting a GLB object from Blender 2.9. The object includes animation that utilises shape keys. The exported file appears microscopic in an external viewer (Threejs). Previous projects/models (including another shape key anim.) fill the viewer correctly by default, but the latest is a tiny dot with limited zoom-in capabilities, before being lost to the near-field boundary.

I've checked that the source models for the basis/shape-keys have the same 1,1,1 scale and are a close fit to the same absolute dimensions. To add extra intrigue; when I select "apply modifiers" in the export settings, the shape key anim. is excluded of course, BUT the initial object displays at the correct size in the viewer. It's something to do with the shape keys, but I am not sure what! (or why it didn't happen previously).

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this, or what I may need to check please?

Thanks,

BHW.

Comment: I think you'll have to provide your blend file for us to be able to help you.  (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's possible that this is a bug in the viewer, too. Does the model appear centered correctly in https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/? If you can share the `.glb` that may help, or you could report a bug on the viewer, which should generally scale things properly by itself.